Unable to execute `npm run build` for Vue3 project due to an error
I have build a project in Vue3 and now I'm trying to npm run build the project (node version 20.17.0). I'm getting following error (in node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:469:56 - '?' expected):
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                               12:02:09 PM
error  in node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:469:56
TS1005: '?' expected.
467 |             // If ReportingObserver check is removed, the type here will form a circular reference in TS5.0+lib.dom.d.ts
468 |             ReportingObserver: any;

469 |             DecompressionStream: infer T extends object;
|                                                        ^
470 |         } ? T
471 |             // TS 4.8, 4.9, 5.0
472 |             : typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any; TransformStream: { prototype: infer T } } ? {

ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
Error: Build failed with errors.
Please advise.
The npm run serve runs just fine. Here the package.json file:
{
  "name": "[hidden]",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-vue": "^4.2.8",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^8.8.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.11.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.3.6",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.3.1",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.13.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue-select": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}

It's a simple admin panel running on localhost:8080

Why do you use Webpack? You should use Vite and Node v22.

Great question kissu. I'll reconfigure the project to use Vite and Node v22.

Please don't post images of code or errors. Instead, copy and paste them into the question, especially with that theme!

I was able to make it work with Vite and Node v22 - thanks @kissu

After a migration towards Vite and Node v22, OP solved the issue.
